# how to constrain parallel inserts?

Tags: database, jdbc

I want to constrain parallel inserts in a table so each logged in user is only able to create lets say 5 inserts. I did find a solution for some databases that seems to work and it goes like this:

1. begin unit of work
2. insert to database
3. read current number of records for the current user, with transaction isolation level uncommitted.
4. check constrain for use, rollback if violated.

This seems to work for HSQLDB, (stable version) of H2 and Derby.
The latest H2 version fails to constrain the inserts, maybe a bug in H2.

I wonder how to solve this problem with Oracle DB which doesn't even support read uncommitted.

My test code is available [here](https://github.com/thomasmey/MaxUsersJdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/de/m3y3r/MaxParallelConstraintTest.java). For convenience, it's copied below:

```
package de.m3y3r;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MaxParallelConstraintTest {

    private DataSource ds;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

        // HSQLDB, test okay
        ds.setDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1");

        // H2, test fail
//      ds.setDriver(new org.h2.Driver());
//      ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db1");

        // Derby, tests okay
//      ds.setDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
//      ds.setUrl("jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true");

//      ds.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
//      ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
//      ds.setMinIdle(10);

        try(Connection c = ds.getConnection()) {
            c.createStatement().execute("create table users (id integer not null primary key, name varchar(32) )");
//          c.createStatement().execute("insert into users (id, name) values (1, 'tom')");
//          c.createStatement().execute("truncate table users");
//          c.commit();
        }
        this.ds = ds;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxConstraint() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        final int maxInserts = 10;
        final int maxNoUsers = 5;

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxInserts);
        final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(maxInserts);

        final Random r = new Random();
        Runnable code = () -> {
            try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()) {
//              System.out.println("isoSup="+ con.getMetaData().supportsTransactionIsolationLevel(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED));

                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
//              con.commit();

                PreparedStatement psIns = con.prepareStatement("insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)");
                PreparedStatement psCheck = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from users");

                int id = r.nextInt();
                psIns.setInt(1, id);
                psIns.setString(2, "name-of-user-" + id);
                int cnt = psIns.executeUpdate();
//              System.out.println("INS " + System.nanoTime() + '-' + Thread.currentThread() + " cnt=" + cnt);
//              psIns.close();

//              con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
                ResultSet rs = psCheck.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()) {
                    int noUsers = rs.getInt(1);
//                  System.out.println("CHK " + System.nanoTime() + '-' + Thread.currentThread() + " noUsers="+noUsers);
                    if(noUsers > maxNoUsers) {
                        System.out.println("max users " + noUsers + " reached rollback");
                        con.rollback();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                rs.close();
//              psCheck.close();

                con.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        };
        for(int i=0,n=maxInserts; i < n; i++) exec.execute(code);
        cdl.await();
        exec.shutdown();

        int noUsers = 0;
        try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement psCheck = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from users");
            ResultSet rs = psCheck.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) noUsers = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        Assert.assertThat(noUsers, Matchers.lessThanOrEqualTo(maxNoUsers));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to run the same application against many different RDBMS? Is there only one application/client connected to the DB?

Comment: Yes, unit tests against h2 in oracle mode and in deployed app against oracle. Multi node installation for failover.